# Rspec capybara - checking a checkbox suppose to be triggering AJAX request but not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have form that has an `delivery_address` input field and checkbox that will trigger an `AJAX` call to retrieve the *default address* and populate the delivery_address field.

This feature is working fine on the browser! But when I am trying to write a test for it on `rspec`, it doesn't seems to work

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
   <label for="order_delivery_address">Delivery address</label>
   <input type="text" name="order[delivery_address]" id="order_delivery_address" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
   <label class="default-address-label">
     <input type="checkbox" name="default_address" id="default_address" value="1">
       Use my default address
    </label>
</div>
```

JS snippet:

```
var $order_details_form = $('.order-details-form');
var $delivery_address_input = $order_details_form.find('#order_delivery_address');

$order_details_form.find('#default_address').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')){ //checkbox is tick
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/order-details/get-user-default-address',
        data: {
           'userId': $order_details_form.find('#order_user_id').val()
        },
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data) {        
          //populate the delivery address input field with default address        
          var default_address = data.default_address;
          $delivery_address_input.val(default_address);
       },
       error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
          //display error message and uncheck the default address checkbox
          toastr.error('Error retrieving your default address at the moment. Please try again.');
          $order_details_form.find('#default_address').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Controller snippet:

```
def get_user_default_address
    default_address = User.find(params[:userId]).address.full_address
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => { :default_address => default_address } }
    end
end
```

Rspec snippet:

```
context 'default address' do
  let!(:user){ create :user }
  let!(:address1){ create :address, user: user}

  it 'should proceed with default address selected', js: true do
    expect(page.current_path).to eq(order_details_path)    
    expect(find('#order_user_id', visible: false).value).to eq(user.id.to_s)
    expect(page.find('#default_address')).to_not be_checked
    check 'default_address'
    expect(page.find('#default_address')).to be_checked
    expect(page.find('#order_delivery_address').value).to eq address1.full_address
  end
end
```

The test result fails at this line `expect(page.find('#order_delivery_address').value).to eq address1.full_address`, where I got empty string instead of the address which indicates that the delivery_address field wasn't populated.

I think it doesn't seems to be even making the AJAX request because I've tried inserting `binding.pry` into the controller `get_user_default_address` and the `binding.pry` is not even triggered.

Any idea what am I missing out here? Any help would be appreciated!

*Note: i am using capybara webkit and it has been configured properly as my other test cases that uses js works successfully.

Comment: do you have any check for login user? authenticate or something?

Comment: @Manishh Yes i do and this could be causing the issue! Two before actions :require_order & :require_user in the controller. Upon visiting the page, two of this action is executed, and after that when calling the AJAX, only one action (:require order) is executed and the other one seems to be not executed at all, which is very strange because i have both user and order present! Any idea what might cause this behaviour?

Comment: what :require_user is doing? I have feeling that your AJAX is being sent to the controller but is not reaching your controller due to authentication failure. Can you please check for them? or have a before_action before other two and put your byebug or pry in that before action

Comment: :require_user just check if user is logged in and redirect to home page if not logged in. please ignore my previous comment about one before_action executed because that was triggered from previous page before visiting the current page.

after checking again, the AJAX doesnt seem to be sent to the controller at all because i've removed all the before_action and  replaced it with a test before_action specifically for 'get_user_default_address' method. The pry in that test action is still not executed

Comment: so the problem is not about authentication. You are saying that `the AJAX doesnt seem to be sent to the controller`, so I believe the problem is with your js part of the functionality. Did you test this outside Rspec? does it work?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to debug the js code with rspec, for sure you can debug the js code outside of rspec, but if this is specific problem with rspec and you can not debug, I would just edit the js code to give you some additional info about why the specs are failing, break the steps, start updating the view and check with rspec if the view it is updated then try to do the ajax request and check if the ajax request is being successfully done (in the js), then check if the controller is a request, at which route etc...

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio yup this works on the browser. turns out the issue is caused by js. thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually caused by one of three things.

1. Not actually using a JS capable driver for the test.  You claim it is running with capybara-webkit, which is a JS capable driver, and that other tests work fine with JS so this is probably not the issue.
2. Error in JS.  By default, in dev mode each JS asset is loaded separately but in test and production modes they are all concatenated into one file to reduce the number of requests. This means that an error in any one of your JS assets that is concatenated before the JS snippet which handles your delivery address checkbox can cause the handler to never get attached. That combined with the fact that capybara-webkit only really supports up to ES5 (without polyfill/transpiling) means you can end up with "errors" in your JS that aren't actually errors in the real browser you're testing with (use of let, const, ES5.1+ methods, etc).  You can see if this is the issue by enabling debug mode in capybara-webkit to see if that shows errors and/or running with selenium and a real browser to see if the issue goes away.
3. Use of the wrong RSpec matchers. The RSpec provided `eq` matcher doesn't provide any sort of waiting/retrying behavior. When combined with the fact there is no guarantee all side effects triggered by an action initiated in the browser have completed when Capybaras `check`/`click`/etc return means you will potentially have all sorts of flaky tests/failures.  Instead you should be using the Capybara provided RSpec matchers which provide waiting/retrying behavior. As a general rule you shouldn't be using the `eq` matcher for anything to do with elements on your page. In your case that would mean your test becoming

   ```
   it 'should proceed with default address selected', js: true do
     expect(page).to have_current_path(order_details_path) # NEVER use `eq` matcher with current_path
     expect(find('#order_user_id', visible: false).value).to eq(user.id.to_s)
     expect(page).to have_unchecked_field('default_address') # same as have_field('default_address', checked: false)
     check 'default_address'
     expect(page).to have_checked_field('default_address')
     expect(page).to have_field('order_delivery_address', with: address1.full_address)
   end
   ```

   The one use of `eq` that remains in that test is because the Capybara :field selector doesn't find inputs of type 'hidden' (which I assume #order_user_id is) and once you're on the order_details_path the input should already exist. Therefore this is one of the few cases where using the `eq` matcher would be acceptable, if you REALLY need to verify this input. Generally you shouldn't be worried about verifying anything the user can't see in a feature test since it's an implementation detail, and if the value was missing/wrong it would show in a test that verifies the functionality of submitting the form.

Comment: turns out it's issue no.2. after display the console logs, there is an Reference error in the JS prior to JS snippet which caused the JS snippet to not be attached. thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @ShaunWan You're welcome -- don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so your question gets marked as answered.  You should also pay attention to no. 3 as you write your future tests, you can see most of the Capybara provided RSpec matchers here - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/RSpecMatchers .